# Getting a 'Error 720 - A connection to the remote computer could not be established.' windows 8

Tags: windows-8, vpn

I have a user who gets 'Error 720 - A connection to the remote computer could not be established.' when trying to connect to any VPN using windows VPN on Windows 8.

I do not think this is an issue with the set up of the VPN as it works for all other users.

I have tried disabling windows firewall and disabling Zone Alarm anti Virus.

The laptop is a 64-bit running windows 8.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot see why this will not work.

Comment: Have you tried using ping to the VPN server from the computer?

Answer (score 0):

I've had loads of issues recently creating VPN's in Windows 8 (or at least my users creating VPN's) due Windows 8 not propagating the security settings whatsoever.

Click the network (monitor or wireless signal) icon in the bottom-right of the screen
Right-click your new VPN connection and select View connection properties
In the dialogue box, click the security tab, under Type of VPN select Point to Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) 
Select the radio button Allow these protocols, then tick Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol (CHAP) and Microsoft CHAP version 2 (MSCHAP v2) and click OK
Try again and see if this has fixed the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think this would make any difference, the VPN is set up to use Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol with IPsec (L2TP/IPSec). So I suspect changing this would cause even more issues.

Comment: Ah fair enough that one already set then yeah? Windows 8 caused us loads of headaches not automatically populating these settings with the defaults. 

Can you make sure IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules and IPsec Policy Agent are both started and set to start Automatically.

Comment: Appologies for the delay in reply, was waiting on the user getting back to me. Yeah all settings are correct for the VPN as it works on other laptops. All the right services are running. I've been reading on line about WAN miniports in windows 8 not installing correctly or being broken. They have to be removed an installed again but this is not a simple process. Any other idea would be greatly apreciated, this issue is really starting to annoy me.

Comment: No worries Albert, well I would like to think about the other end. I don't know what your connecting too however if its Windows Server RRAS then you get some good logs/info from the Server as to what is going on (if of course the connection is even getting there/being attempted).

Comment: I really doubt it is anything to do with the server, I have other windows 8 users that can connect to the VPN with no issues and from what I can see there is no difference in the way their machines are set up to the one that is causing the issues. It's a really strange one...

Comment: Nothing so much with the Server however if you rename the log files for RRAS and get the user to test a connection during an isolated period you will get some good logs file to help you troubleshoot. They are stored in Windows\Tracing however you have to enable them first and the level of logging you require.

Comment: The logs files are handy for Server and Workstation issues as it will further explain why the connection is failing.